# DDD throwing exception or passing borken rules for invalid entity

Tags: c#, validation, domain-driven-design

Before I ask you exactly at what point I need your help, let me give you brief idea about the architecture of DDD based website.

**Database** (Anti Corruption Layer - I use simplified terminology)

**Domain** (Domain Model/Entity/Aggregate)

**Repository** (Call Database layer and create/save entity, ***should throw validation exception/return broken rules***)

**Service** (Call repository under and given Unit Of Work context)

**MVC** (Call service to get object)

- **Model** (***Validation are handled here***)
- **ModelView**
- **Controller**

This is how my system works (I supposed it to work :p)

For Save operation entity field validation are done at 2 level;

1. Client side validation (html page)
2. Server side validation

But at server side, Model doesn't validate entity field but rather try to save entity. Real validation are done in repository before saving entity. So, if entity is in invalid state (some of the rules are checked at server side only / some error occurred in javascript code), it would throw error associated with each fields or it simply pass list of broken rules. Model will then set error associated with each field which will be displayed in page using error tooltip.

Now, the thing what is the best way to pass broken rules from service to MVC model?

Comment: You shouldn't implement validation (as in business rules) in the repository. The repository is there ONLY to save/retrieve objects.

Comment: @MikeSW, then where should I validate entity? Not every entities can be validated as soon as they get changed? For an example, if combination of 2 properties have different rules on the basis of their values then how would you validate the entity?

Comment: The entity should not allow invalid values so the validation is done when the values are set. It really depends on a concrete scenario, it's not a general rule for that. It also depends on good modeling.

Answer (score 1):

1. Distinguish Model and View Model. Entities should always be valid. There should be no method able to put it in an invalid state. Oh! you just set its properties in the form? This is not DDD. This is CRUD with Anemic Domain Model. View Model can be validated using validation attributes and any other nice way. You should return the list of broken validation rules rather than throw exceptions.
2. Distinguish Validation Rules and Business Rules. This first are context-free, can be checked on client side, they are about the form(at) (data making sense) rather than content (command can be processed). Business rules should be checked in entities methods that are the only way of changing their state. So you provide valid arguments to the method and it decides if they are also acceptable. If not, the exception is one of the ways of communicating it. But you can also consider alternatives, like domain events.

Comment: Lol I've just [blogged](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2014/05/08/A-Way-To-Provide-Immediate-Feedback-With-CQRS-Commands.aspx) exactly about point 2

Comment: @Bartłomiej, I didn't stripped logic out of domain and my entity still validate itself and set it's state when any property is changed. So, I don't think it's Anemic Domain Model. I'm still wondering how would you change the property of entity without passing to the Model? In simple term, service should not pass entity to presenter or controller. Is that what you are telling?

Comment: @Bartłomiej, by the way after starting this thread yesterday, I came to know about Domain Event and I think it's great idea (may be the best solution). The question is how to raise event in Controller when Entity is invalid?

Comment: @ParthPatel Domain events have nothing to do with validation. And in 99% of cases a controller should never know about domain entities. Btw, the Model can mean many things, are you referring to MVC model, the domain model etc?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I Model refers MVC model, while Entity refers domain model. Btw, my controller doesn't know anything but ViewModel. Actually, logic to get/update Entity is inside MVC model.

Comment: MVC model is just a representation of user's form it shouldn't contain any update logic. This should be handled by an application layer.